# Ember.js: Which controller is in charge?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

### What I've got

ember-cli POD structure.
I've got nested routes and so the following folder-structure:

```
|
|_pods
     |_items
          |_index
          |     |_controller.js
          |     |_route.js
          |     |_template.hbs
          |_item
                |_controller.js
```

I'm loading all the item-records of my model in the model-hook of items/index/route.js. In my index-template, I'm iterating over all items from the item model.

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

That works fine. Now I want to call some properties from the alpha (singular) controller, so I added the itemController-Properties in the each-helper:

```
{{#each model itemController='items.item' as |item|}}
```

now I can access properties in my template for each item like `{{item.myTestMethod}}` which is defined in the alpha-controller.

### What is the Problem?

But for some reason, other parts between the each-loop aren't accessible anymore (like `{{item.title}}` which is a model property). Also, the Ember-Inspector show me now two more entries in the "View Tree"-Tab, one for every item within the each-loop.

Can anybody explain me that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers no longer proxy properties from the model.  You need to fully qualify the property you want to access.  The model is now the property `model` on the controller (which is what item is now).

#### Property on the model

```
{{item.model.title}}
```

#### Property on the controller

```
{{item.fooProp}}
```

Comment: I thank you so much!!
But how can I access the properties from the controller itself?
**items/index/controller.js**
`test: function() {
    console.log("items-controller: " + this.get('model.title'));
  }.property('model.title')`

brings undefinied. In my template, it is possible to access the parent model directly just through `{{model.items}}` - but not in the controller for the index-route

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but Isn't the model in your index route the collection of items?  So `title` doesn't exist on the collection itself, but on each individual item.  `test: function() { console.log("items-controller: " + this.get('model').getEach('title')); }.property('model.@each.title')`